# Php cast to int returns double

Tags: php, casting, type-conversion

Can somebody tell me please why this `code` returns `double` in `php`?

```
$personal_id = ((int) $person['born_number'] * 2);
```

`Gettype($personal_id)` returns `double` like this `4294967294.0`

How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: try `intval($person['born_number'] * 2)`;

Comment: Сause your number is too big for integer?

Comment: Yes it is too big for integer. But how to solve it in elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why double? Because variable doens't fit into integer size.

You may use gmp for emulating big integer. http://php.net/manual/en/intro.gmp.php

But i think it's overengineering. What if use string instead of integer?

```
$personalId = sprintf("%.0f", ($a*2));
```

Comment: This looks pretty fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
$personal_id = floor($person['born_number'] * 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try `intval()` [(cf. official documentation)](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.intval.php)

```
$personal_id = intval($person['born_number'] * 2);
```

Comment: intval() returns -2 in this case.

Comment: It's too big for an int, you need to change $person['born_number']. How will you use it, and where does it come from ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$personal_id = (int)($born_number * 2);
```

Comment: you need to change the variable with your original one.